# How can I title a box?

Tags: boxes, frame-title

I was trying to a title inserted on the lines of a box. I don't know if LaTeX has a command or a package for doing this, but it's something similar to the image below.
[image: There is an example of what I'm trying to do.]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are some packages that can do this: `mdframed`, `tcolorbox`, `fancybox` etc., but there's not a command out of the box for this.

Answer (score 11):

With [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) it is not so difficult:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm, a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    tikznode boxed title,
    enhanced,
    arc=0mm,
    interior style={white},
    attach boxed title to top center= {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={size=normal,colframe=white,boxrule=0pt},
    title={#1}}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{mybox}{Short title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I compiled the above I got the following error. ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `many' for package `tcolorbox'.

Comment: I have the version 3.80 from 2015/11727 (I thing it is recent). This option is listed on page 9 of `tcolorbox` manual. See in your manual which version you have. Try to upgrade your installation.

Answer (score 2):

When you need not to break these frames to more pages, then you can create a short macro using TeX primitives and basic plain TeX macros:

```
\def\linefil{\leaders\vrule height.4pt\hfill}
\def\ftitle#1#2{\bigskip\hbox{\vrule \vbox{\noindent 
  \linefil \quad \smash{\lower.5ex\hbox{\bf #1}}\quad \linefil\null \par
  \nointerlineskip \vbox{\bigskip\leftskip=1.5em \rightskip=1.5em #2\bigskip}
  \hrule}\vrule}}

\ftitle   {Title}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur massa turpis,
semper quis fringilla ut, viverra nec risus. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nunc
lorem, sollicitudin vel sodales eget, vehicula nec mi. Proin ullamcorper rutrum
nibh, at porttitor nunc euismod et. Donec faucibus nisi faucibus ipsum porttitor
pharetra. Sed elementum, lectus nec congue imperdiet, ipsum leo viverra nisi, sit
amet commodo odio odio id nisl. Fusce sagittis lobortis nisi sed consectetur.}


\bye
```